# java corda template build issue

Tags: corda

I am new to Corda development and am trying to configure a Corda java template for Hello World, downloaded template while syncing the gradle throwing below error:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jre8/1.1.60/kotlin-stdlib-jre8-1.1.60.jar'.
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.ResourceExceptions.failure(ResourceExceptions.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.ResourceExceptions.getFailed(ResourceExceptions.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.copyToCache(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:198)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.access$300(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor$1.create(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:88)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor$1.create(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:80)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.ProducerGuard$AdaptiveProducerGuard.guardByKey(ProducerGuard.java:97)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.getResource(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.downloadStaticResource(DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.download(ExternalResourceResolver.java:310)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.resolveArtifact(ExternalResourceResolver.java:296)
    ... 27 more
```

build.gradle details

```
   ext {
        corda_release_group = 'net.corda'
        corda_release_version = '3.3-corda'
        corda_gradle_plugins_version = '3.2.1'
        junit_version = '4.12'
        quasar_version = '0.7.9'
        spring_boot_version = '2.0.2.RELEASE'`enter code here`
        spring_boot_gradle_plugin_version = '2.0.2.RELEASE'
        slf4j_version = '1.7.25'
        log4j_version = '2.9.1'
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you are using an older version. The latest Hello World sample has been updated to use the latest 4.3 version. Please use the below link to clone the hello world sample.

https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-java

Comment: The issue got resolved by adding certificates using by keytool.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using an very old version of the CorDapp template. Your build.gradle says Corda version 3.3

Whereas, we are currently 4.4 right now. Please download a copy of the latest template and work on it. https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-java